# Export data of a 3D histogram

Tags: export, histograms

I want to export the data of a three dimensional histogram in the format

```
#   x     y     z
```

with a blank line between different lines, so that one can plot the histogram in gnuplot simply using

```
splot 'data.dat' u 1:2:3 w l
```

What is the right way to obtain that?

Comment: Can you use this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696159/how-to-export-mathematica-data-in-columns

Comment: You could add some code to generate the data you refer to. It should be a fairly trivial task for `Export` - did you already try something along this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how you get your data..

```
example = 
   Transpose@{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1000], 
              RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], 1000]};
Histogram3D[example]
list = HistogramList[example];
x = list[[1, 1]];
y = list[[1, 2]];
data = Flatten[
      MapIndexed[ {x[[#2[[1]]]], y[[#2[[2]]]], #1} &, list[[2]] , {2}], 1];
ListPlot3D[data]
```

now exporting to a gnuplot form..

```
Export["test.txt", data // N, "Table"]
```

I dont have gnuplot on this machine to test but it should be close

Edit.. generalization to higher dimensions:

```
dim = TensorRank[Last@list];
data = Flatten[MapIndexed[ 
         Append[Table[(First@list)[[k, #2[[k]]]], {k, dim}], #1] &, 
         Last@list ,{dim}], dim - 1];
```

Adding blanks, and a header comment:

```
Export["test.txt", 
      Prepend[Riffle[N@data, "  ", 
              1 + Last@Dimensions@Last@list], {"# x y z"}], "Table"]
```

Comment: yes, there is only the further need of a blank line between different blocks

Comment: it doesn't work, it puts the blank line in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok, Fixed that.. the automatic dimensions are not square and I used the wrong dimension in Riffle.

Comment: 0k perfect, thanks